# Session lost and application end, after file download

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I have this code in the end of link button click:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=download.zip");
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("download.zip"));
Response.End();
Response.Flush();
```

to download a zip file from an aspx page.
In the previous page i set a session variable, after going to this download page and download the file, then press back i find the session=null "this happen after downloading more than 1 time", and the application_end in global.ascx called.

Do you know why this may happen??

Note: this is happening on all browsers, on IIS7 both local and on my server.

Comment: You should add Response.Flush() right before Response.End().  But, I do not think this is your problem.

Comment: i added Response.Flush()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a really old article that may help you understand why the application is shutting down.  http://aspalliance.com/902

Comment: after using this code it told me : Website dir change or directory rename
HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown
HostingEnvironment caused shutdown

Comment: note that the download.zip file exist inside a subfolder not in the same folder as the download page.

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem, my problem was in a previous line which was deleting a directory, and as you may know that deleting or renaming a folder inside the website folder will reset the application.

But [JD answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466807/session-lost-and-application-end-after-file-download/2466890#2466890) helped me too much to trace and figure this problem.